# Texture Painting issue - colour randomly showing on wrong faces

Tags: modeling, uv, sculpting, faces, texture-painting

I've sculpted a basic human and I'm now trying to paint it but when I paint an area sometimes the colour appears elsewhere instead of where my cursor is. The face normals are all correct and I've tried playing around with different Island Margin values for the Smart UV unwrap. Even a value of 1 doesn't help. Any other ideas? I've attached a photo of where I've painted around his eye and there are specks of color in other places.[image]

Thanks
Amy

Comment: maybe in the N panel > Tool > Options, check the Bleed value, if it's too high it will paint on the other islands. If it doesn't work, maybe share your file (with image packed): https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, I tried changing the Bleed value to zero and it still did the same thing. I've simplified my topology a bit more so the faces aren't so tightly packed but no luck. Will send you the file and texture image, thanks for helping

Comment: [<img src="https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/embedImage.png?bid=nbnY54l5" />](https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/b/nbnY54l5/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to:

- Unwrap again, your islands are probably overlapping, choose the *Smart UV Project* option with a bit of *Island Margin* (0.03).
- Put a bit of bleeding in the N panel *> Tool > Options* so that the paint correctly covers the islands.
- Your image is currently 1024 pixels large, depending on what kind of shots you want to do it might be a bit too small, so maybe increase the size

Comment: Thank you, a combination of your suggestions, along with simplifying my topology in certain areas even more (the lips, ears and eye sockets were too detailed) resolved the problem. Much appreciated!